# How can I request a unique file name for a new copy of an existing file in V2?

Tags: box-api

In the V2 API, is there a convenient way to upload a new copy of an existing file so that it is given a unique filename (e.g., by appending "(copy_number)" to the original filename)?

I am currently using the https://upload.box.net/api/1.0/new_copy URL from the V1 API to achieve this.  Is there an equivalent way to accomplish this using the V2 API?

Answer (score 0):

The [Copy a File](http://developers.box.com/docs/#files-copy-a-file) API method will do exactly this.  You can specify a new name and/or parent folder.

Comment: But I want the convenience that was available with the new_copy feature from V1.  That is, I want to upload a new copy of the file (with changed content) in the same folder, and I want Box to automatically give it a unique name to avoid overwriting an existing file with the same name.

Comment: That doesn't exist anymore, to the best of my knowledge.  This is now a two-step operation (copy + write.)